# Handling files with Turbo C

Tags: c, file, turbo-c

I have to make a program that manages info it obtains from a file, but I'm using Turbo C 3.0 which is ancient, so I'm getting errors trying to write to the file, here is my code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
clrscr();

int c;
FILE *datos;

datos = fopen("datos.txt","w");

c = fgetc (datos);

printf("%d",c);

fclose(datos);

getch();
}
```

Whenever I print it I get -1 as return. I know this must be something really simple but I'm having issues.

Comment: Why you `fopen`ed file with "w" (write mode) and not with "r" (Read mode)?

Comment: @osgx because eventually i'll be writing to the file

Comment: Why are you using Turbo C 3.0? (I learned to program using Turbo C myself, but that was a long time ago...)

Comment: i know, i use a lot of other IDE's but i have to use this one for this specific project

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you have a valid file:

```
// use "r" for reading, "w" for writing
datos = fopen("datos.txt", "r");

if (datos)
{
    int ch = fgetc(datos);
    if (ch != EOF)
        printf("%d\n", c);
    else
        printf("End of file!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Failed to open datos.txt for reading.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You open the file in write only mode (`"w"`), but you are trying to read the file with `fgetc`.

Either open the file in read-only mode (`"r"`), then read the data, close the file, and open it again in write only mode to write it. Or open the file in a mode that support both reading and writing - check the documentation of Turbo-C for more info.

Comment: i'm going to have to write to the file eventually, i have changed it also to 'r' but it still does not work

Comment: @IsaacGonzalez Once you open a file with write mode there is no data in it, its truncated. May be you should add some data and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file for "read" instead:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){

  int c;
  FILE *datos;

  clrscr();
  datos = fopen("datos.txt","r");
  if (!datos) {
    printf ("Open failed, errno=%d\n", errno);
    return 1;
  }    
  c = fgetc (datos);
  printf("%d",c);
  fclose(datos);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

If it still fails, tell us the error#.

Comment: it doesn't seems as if it have failed, i just get a 0 in return

Comment: i accidentally erased something in my code, now i get 'end of file!' as an output, the contents of the file are "1234567890"

Answer (score 0):

```
'include statements

main(){
  char we;
  char intt;
  ifstream q("xyz.txt");
  for (we=0;we<100;we++){
    q >> intt;
    printf("%c",q);
   }

  getch();

}
```